# mikrotik - allow one local network to another

Tags: networking, router, ip, mikrotik-routeros

I have Mikrotik, which is default gateway and have old ip pool, which was all static 192.168.1.0/24 (LAN1).

I wanted to start DHCP server, so i dont have to write down all ip assignments.
So i just created IP pool in subnet 192.168.2.0/24 (LAN2) with addresses 192.168.2.50-192.168.2.254

I need to allow all trafic from LAN2 to LAN1. Design is that printers, servers and stuff will be left on static IP on LAN1, so i need to be able to work with LAN1 clients from LAN2.

I already setup firewall rule to allow all trafic from LAN2 to LAN1, so now i can ping to some servers, but not all of them.
also i setup NAT for LAN2 to masquarade.

So with this i have access to internet and have access to only some servers and absolutly none of standard pc clients (cant ping or rdp).

Comment: Why you do not use the same subnet? Find any address range free of current static assignements and set it to a scope. Then reconfigure a lot of stations to DHCP (primarily those which have addresses adjacent to scope). Then expand the scope. Repeat until all stations set to DHCP. And no routing needed.

Comment: i would like to separate servers, printers etc. from basic clients. Also i would sooner or later run out of adresses from one subnet, so why dont kill two flyies with one swing :)

Comment: *i would like to separate servers, printers etc. from basic clients* And what is the point in such subnet separation, if all network nodes will be in one physical segment of the network? *Also i would sooner or later run out of adresses from one subnet* If so use more wide private subnet now (192.168.0.0/22 or 172.16.0.0/16 for example). The problem must be solved before it occurs...

Comment: well for overall clarity, also for better firewall configurations and as i said before, i would run out of IP addresses from 192.168.1.0/24 soon

Comment: 1) What do your 'masquerade' rules look like? There should be _no_ NAT between internal networks. 2) Do you have a rule that allows traffic _back_ from LAN1 to LAN2?

Comment: 1) chain srcnat, src. address 192.168.2.0/24, out. Interface wan_bridge, action masquaerade 2) yes sir

Comment: so i add this to NAT: chain srcnat, src address 192.168.2.0/24 dst. address: 192.168.1.0/24, action masquerade and now its working. is this correct solution?